# Remove GET variables on URL when doing a submit

Tags: c#, .net

I have this problem: I have a page with a datagrid with links that redirect to the same page, adding variables to the URL. Once the user chooses some options in the form, it submits, once again, to itself.

My issue is that I must remove all those variables in the URL or they disrupt the submit. Any way to clean the URL while doing the POST?

Answer (score 0):

No, the POST will happen with the current querystring.

You could add the querystring parameters to Session and negate the need to pass this in via the URL.

Comment: Not a fan of session. Doesn't scale across webservers very nicely. If this can be done statelessly, it's preferable.

Comment: Found a way: Just add a  PostBackUrl="Yourform.aspx" to the button you are using to remove everything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Just need to add a PostBackUrl to the button. Sorry if it was a dumb question.